# SQL percentage of the total

Tags: sql, percentage

Hi how can I get the percentage of each record over the total?
Lets imagine I have one table with the following

```
ID code Points
1   101  2
2   201  3
3   233  4
4   123  1
```

The percentage for `ID 1` is `20%` for `2` is `30%` and so one 
how do I get it?

Comment: Which DBMS you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
select id,code,points,(points * 100)/(select sum(points) from tabel1) from table1
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple approaches to getting that result.

You essentially need the "total" points from the whole table (or whatever subset), and get that repeated on each row. Getting the percentage is a simple matter of arithmetic, the expression you use for that depends on the datatypes, and how you want that formatted.

Here's one way (out a couple possible ways) to get the specified result:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.code
     , t.points
  -- , s.tot_points
     , ROUND(t.points * 100.0 / s.tot_points,1) AS percentage
  FROM onetable t
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(r.points) AS tot_points
           FROM onetable r
       ) s
 ORDER BY t.id
```

The view query `s` is run first, that gives a single row. The join operation matches that row with every row from `t`. And that gives us the values we need to calculate a percentage.

Another way to get this result, without using a join operation, is to use a subquery in the SELECT list to return the total.

---

Note that the join approach can be extended to get percentage for each "group" of records.

```
id  type    points   %type
--  ----    ------   -----
1   sold        11     22%
2   sold         4      8%
3   sold        25     50% 
4   bought       1   50%
5   bought       1   50%
6   sold        10     20%
```

To get that result, we can use the same query, but a a view query for `s` that returns total `GROUP BY r.type`, and then the join operation isn't a CROSS join, but a match based on type:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.type
     , t.points
  -- , s.tot_points_by_type
     , ROUND(t.points * 100.0 / s.tot_points_by_type,1) AS `%type`
  FROM onetable t
  JOIN ( SELECT r.type
              , SUM(r.points) AS tot_points
           FROM onetable r
          GROUP BY r.type
       ) s
    ON s.type = t.type
 ORDER BY t.id
```

To do that same result with the subquery, that's going to be a correlated subquery, and that subquery is likely to get executed for every row in `t`.

This is why it's more natural for me to use a join operation, rather than a subquery in the SELECT list... even when a subquery works the same.  (The patterns we use for more complex queries, like assigning aliases to tables, qualifying all column references, and formatting the SQL... those patterns just work their way back into simple queries. The rationale for these patterns is kind of lost in simple queries.)

Comment: Somewhat unrelated side question: Are database able to detect that the result of the subselect is constant and thus only evaluate it once?

Comment: @Martin Thurau: Yes, a good optimizer should recognize that the subquery can be run once, and then use that constant. (Effectively converting the subquery in the select list into the same operation specified in my query. But the optimizer won't do that if it's a correlated subquery; say you were getting the total points of different types (say "bought" and "sold"), and you wanted a percentage based on the type. It's easy to get an efficient plan with the join; if you make it a correlated subquery in the select list, then that subquery will get executed for every row.

Answer (score 0):

To add to a good list of responses, this should be fast performance-wise, and rather easy to understand:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, code VARCHAR(256), Points INT)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1,'101',2), (2,'201',3),(3,'233',4), (4,'123',1)

;WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT * FROM @T)
SELECT C.*, CAST(ROUND((C.Points/B.TOTAL)*100, 2) AS DEC(32,2)) [%_of_TOTAL]
FROM CTE C
JOIN (SELECT CAST(SUM(Points) AS DEC(32,2)) TOTAL FROM CTE) B ON 1=1
```

Just replace the table variable with your actual table inside the CTE.

Comment: We should note that this syntax is for SQL Server. This syntax won't work in other databases (e.g. Oracle, MySQL, Teradata, et al.)

Comment: Yes, true. Darn, I had tagged sql-server for my search, but this is just sql. :( But yes, this script is indeed created only for SQL Server 2008 and later.

Comment: I'm not sure it this is even faster than having one extra query to get the total like in @sathish answer.